# Event run before click button

Tags: javascript, dom, simple-html-dom

this is my code :

```
<body>
    <button id="mybtn">Click Me!</button>
     <script>
         document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick = sum(2,5);
        function sum(a,b) {
            document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = a + b;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

why document show 7 before click button?

Comment: `onclick = function(){sum(2,5);}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what happened there you are executing the function instead of assigning it

here is a solution :

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick = function(){ sum(2,5) };
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @NetaMeta's answer you can use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method to create new function from `sum` function and prepend parameters:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick = sum.bind(null, 2, 5);
```